# invalid configuration exception unrecognized option assets under framework symfony2

Tags: symfony-2.8

Hi everyone can you help me to resolve this problem ?
. I am trying to install FosUserBundle and when i type any command i get this exception

[image]

This is my config file

[image]

I couldn't find any solution in google or blogs

Comment: Please, add a simple text description to your pictures.

Comment: Sorry, i'm trying to install FosUserBundle and when i type any command like this "doctrine:shema:update i get this error

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line under framework:

```
assets: ~
```